# code works from console, but doesn't work in method

Tags: php, sqlite, doctrine-orm

I made sqlite database using doctrine 2. When i run *create_product.php* from console it works fine, but i want to create product from php class. So i made method with *create_product.php* code and included *bootstrap.php*, but i had issue: Undefined variable: entityManager.

*create_product.php*

```
<?php
// create_product.php
require_once "bootstrap.php";

    $name = 'name';
    $date = date("d.m.Y");
    $time = time();

    $product = new Product();
    $product->setName($name);
    $product->setSaveDate($date);
    $product->setSaveTime($time);

    $entityManager->persist($product);
    $entityManager->flush();
echo "Created product with ID " . $response->getId() . "\n";
?>
```

and php class file:

```
<?php
namespace app\monitor;
use Product;

require_once dirname(dirname(dirname(__DIR__))) . "/bootstrap.php";

class Service {

public function work() {
       $name = 'name';
       $this->saveProduct($name);   

public function saveProduct($name) {

        $date = date("d.m.Y");
        $time = time();

        $entity = new Product();
        $entity->setName($name);
        $entity->setSaveTime($time);
        $entity->setSaveDate($date);

        $entityManager->persist($entity);
        $entityManager->flush();
    }
}
```

Why it's work from console, but doesn't work in method?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you can't call method inside body class (not in a other method). Secondly $entityManager will be null (it's not a saveProduct method variable).

Comment: Okey, but what can i do to save $entity in database with saveProduct method?

Comment: get an entity manager from depedency injection container (if you're using symfony-like application). I don't know how to get without it. Maybe try to include bootstrap inside method saveProduct but it's a very dirty way :)